# Reassigning C++ reference variables

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am trying to understand C++ reference variables. This link seems to indicate that a pointer can be reassigned while a reference should be assigned at initialization. [difference between pointer and reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in). I have the following code below. I have run it on a debian system. The output is also shown below. The output seems to indicate that reference can be reassigned as well.It would be great if someone could clarify.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 6;
  int *p; 

  p = &x; 
  cout << "content of p " << *p << endl;

  p = &y; 
  cout << "content of p " << *p << endl;

  *p = 10; 
  cout << "content of p " << *p << endl;

  /*A reference must be assigned at initialization*/
  int &r = x;
  cout << "content of r " << r << endl;

  r = y;
  cout << "content of r " << r << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
content of p 5
content of p 6
content of p 10
content of r 5
content of r 10
```

Comment: A reference cannot be reassigned. If you think it can, then your test isn't thorough enough.

Comment: Here `r = y;` does the same as `x = y;`. It does not assign the reference, it assigns the thing the reference refers to.

Comment: Reference cannot be reassigned means `&r` will never change. `r` can change in case of reference-to-non-const.

Comment: "content of p" is not correct. `p` holds a pointer, but the output is not displaying the value of the pointer; it's displaying the value that the pointer points at. Don't every lose track of the difference between a pointer and the thing it points at.

Answer (score 3):

What you see here is the value being assigned to the variable referenced by the referencing variable.

In other words: 
You did not assign new value to the **referencing** variable. You assigned a new value to the **referenced** variable.