# C++ trying to reassign a reference to instance object

Tags: c++, reference

Trying to understand how reassignment of references is blocked in C++. I understand that as in [Reassigning C++ reference variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302034/reassigning-c-reference-variables)
the reference itself cant be reassigned but the value of the refree is being changed. But I want to understand how this works for instance objects

For below code

```
class A{};

A aobj;  
A& aref = aobj;
A bobj; 
aref = bobj;
```

Want to understand if above is legal and whats happening here.

If its legal then I am not able to understand how does it work. Are we just changing the value the variable 'aobj' holds? Then isent that same as 'aref' referring now to object 'bobj'

If its illegal is it considered as an attempt to reassign a reference?

Comment: "*I understand that ... the reference itself cant be reassigned but the value of the refree is being changed*" If you understand that, it isn't clear why you're asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal. What this does:

```
aref = bobj;
```

is assign `bobj` to `aobj`. The reference `aref` is not re-seated; it still refers to `aobj`. But now `aobj` is a copy of `bobj`, assuming sensible assignment semantics. In other words, it's the same as if you had said:

```
aboj = bobj;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `aref` refers to `aobj`, then `aref` behaves exactly the same as `aobj` in most contexts (by definition).

In particular, `aref = bobj` has exactly the same effect `aobj = bobj` would have.  There's nothing more to it. `aref` doesn't suddenly stop referring to `aobj` and start referring to `bobj` just because you did `aobj = bobj`, so `aobj = bobj` doesn't have this effect either.